# ripple effect animation

Tags: iphone, ios, core-animation, uiviewanimation

I'm developing iPhone app for aquarium. In that i used ripple effect code as follows:

```
CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

[animation setDelegate:self];
[animation setDuration:0.6];
[animation setTimingFunction: [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

animation.type = @"rippleEffect";
animation.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeBackwards;
animation.startProgress = 0.4;
[animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];

[self.view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"rippleEffect"];
[self performSelector:@selector(fn_btnOperation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.40];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.70];
```

It's working great, but the problem is after calling this animation: tableview, textview, scrollview in my app are not working properly. Scroll is getting delay and it's not smooth. Could anyone fix this problem?

Comment: You never close the animation with [UIView commitAnimations]

Answer (score 1):

Beware that that transition effect is undocumented. I asked Apple's engineers about using animation types that are not in the docs. They said that while their automated tools will not detect this sort of thing, it is still an undocumented API, and as such, is against their guidelines and you risk your app being rejected if you use them.

Since you are using an undocumented transition effect, you are on your own as far as figuring out how to make it work correctly.